# Getting bad request error in Windows push notifications using Windows App SDK

Tags: c++, windows, push-notification, windows-app-sdk, wns

I have a win 32 style app which is purely in C++ and I was trying to use push notifications for Windows applications. As, these push notifications have the capability to start the app even when it is not running so was thinking to have this in application.

Now, many documentations are either UWP based, or C# based examples, but I have found this code and was thinking to try this out. I am following the same document, but I am facing few issues.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/notifications/push-notifications/push-quickstart

I am trying out this unpackaged one where Windows has provided this example, https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/blob/main/Samples/Notifications/Push/cpp-console-unpackaged/cpp-console-unpackaged.cpp

I was able to get the generated Azure app Id, was able to get the Channel URI, created a client secret and was trying to use POSTMAN app to send push notifications for my app.

Now, before sending any notifications we need to get the bearer access token, adding screenshot below of what I have added in the POSTMAN app. Why is it giving me a Bad Request error?

Edit: It says that as invalid client id so, it is giving me a bad request error.

[image]

Edit: Tried another from Internet, that POST Url should be [https://login.microsoftonline.com/"PleaseAddTenantID"/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%22PleaseAddTenantID%22/oauth2/v2.0/token)

Then error that I faced:

> "error_description": "AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://notify.windows.com was not found in the tenant named "XXX-XXX".

Comment: Have you checked the document [Push notification service request and response headers (Windows Runtime apps)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/push-request-response-headers)? for example *scope TRUE Must be set to notify.windows.com*.

Comment: Have you solved your question? The `scope` parameter must be set to *notify.windows.com*.